# How can the context of getServerSideProps be accessed in different functions and components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to migrate an app from CRA to Nextjs.
With CRA and CSR, the cookies and url data can be fetched in any function and any component but with the server side rendered code in Nextjs, getServerSideProps has access to that data through the context object received in the arguments.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    childFunction(...arguments, context)
    childComponent(..arguments, context)
}
```

Now I forced to pass through this context object as argument to all the child functions and child components, if it is required 10 levels deep, I am forced to modify every function to accept the context object as an argument and handle it in the return

Comment: You can make use of [React Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) in your component. Show a loading UI, until you don't have the data, and once you've it, set the context and show the children, so that they've access to the data.

Comment: How can I set a custom context inside getServerSideProps ? Hooks are illegal to use in getServerSideProps.                                                                                             
const useServerContext = () => useContext(ServerContext);                                               This is illegal to access or set the existing context I received.